# Converting an array of hashes to ONE hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes with arrays that look something like this:

```
result = [
  {"id_t"=>["1"], "transcript_t"=>["I am a transcript ONE"]},
  {"id_t"=>["2"], "transcript_t"=>["I am a transcript TWO"]},
  {"id_t"=>["3"], "transcript_t"=>["I am a transcript THREE"]}
]
```

What I would LIKE to do, if possible, is transform it such that it becomes ONE hash where each key=>value pair is taken from the values of each hash. I don't think I'm explaining that well, so here's what I mean:

```
end_result = {
  "1"=>"I am a transcript ONE",
  "2"=>"I am a transcript TWO",
  "3"=>"I am a transcript THREE"
}
```

I've been scouring Stack Overflow and Google for various methods, but I've gotten myself confused in the process. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you written any code to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there any chance the array associated with the `transcript_t` keys will ever have more than one element?

Comment: @theTinMan I got it to the initial point, but I won't lie, I didn't know how to begin this final transformation. I've been looking for fuller explanations of map for this. The array for transcript_t will never have more than one value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the key to the solution is `Hash[]`, which will create a Hash based on an array of key/values, i.e.

```
Hash[[["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]]
#=> {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"}
```

Just add a set of `map`, and you have a solution!

```
result = [
  {"id_t"=>["1"], "transcript_t"=>["I am a transcript ONE"]},
  {"id_t"=>["2"], "transcript_t"=>["I am a transcript TWO"]},
  {"id_t"=>["3"], "transcript_t"=>["I am a transcript THREE"]}
]
Hash[result.map(&:values).map(&:flatten)]
```

Comment: Well, that works perfectly. Thanks! Is there a good resource for explaining best practices with using map somewhere? I keep needing it but never know how to implement it.

Comment: @librarion `map(&:values)` is actually a shortcut for `map {|h| h.value }` (well, almost, it actually calls `to_proc` on the method `value`, so it's slower, but easier to read).
I do not have a resource for explaining best practices for `map`, but whenever you need to iterate over an enumerable to return a modified version of it, `map` (or it's change in place variant `map!`) is always the way to go.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you can have a look at apidock: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map

Comment: There's even a video! :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=1zWj9BReAX8

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
result.inject({}){|acc, hash| acc[hash.values[0][0]] = hash.values[1][0]; acc }

=> { "1"=>"I am a transcript ONE", 
     "2"=>"I am a transcript TWO",
     "3"=>"I am a transcript THREE" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using a combo of [Enumerable#inject](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3/enumerable#method-i-inject) and [Hash#merge](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3/hash#method-i-merge):

```rb
result.inject({}) do |acc, hash|
   acc.merge({hash['id_t'].first => hash['transcript_t'].first})
end
=> { "1"=>"I am a transcript ONE",
     "2"=>"I am a transcript TWO",
     "3"=>"I am a transcript THREE" }
```

This minimizes the need for `[]`-constructions, and the additional explicit return appendix of `; acc`.